# Reformatting syncronous code to asyncronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, callback

I have a method that traverses an array syncronously, and then returns a datastructure to the caller. Logically the function does something like this:

```
const myFunction = (inputarray) => {
  let returnarray = [];
  for (let element of inputarray){
    let returnelement = {
      a: element.A,
      b: element.B
    }
    if (returnelement.b == 5){
      returnelement.c = a + b;
    }
    returnarray.push(returnelement);
  }
  return returnarray;
}
```

So far so good. However, I realise that to property fill `returnelement.c` I need to get some stuff from my database. I'm using a MongoDB database with mongoose. So I'm going to use `element.a` to get something that I put into `c`. That means I need to make an asyncronous call to get this data.

```
const myFunction = (inputarray) => {
  let returnarray = [];
  for (let element of inputarray){
    let returnelement = {
      a: element.A,
      b: element.B
    }
    if (returnelement.b == 5){
      MyType.find({ key: returnelement.b }, (err, value) => {
        returnelement.c = value;
      });
    }
    returnarray.push(returnelement);
  }
  return returnarray;
}
```

This obviously won't work. My function will not wait for the async calls to complete, and will just return after it's done looping through the array.

I want to have the function return the finished structure to the caller when all values are gotten from the database. I guess that means I need to refactor my method to be async as well and call an callback when it's done, but I can't see a clean method to do this. I can't call the callback inside mongooses callback, since I can't be sure that the callback is the last one to complete. I don't even know how many of the iterations in the for-loop that will even make a database call. (`returnelement.b == 5`).

One thought is to make a variable that starts as the length of the array, and deducts 1 for each callback that resolves, and deducts 1 if `returnelement.b != 5`, and when that value reach 0 in a callback, we call the callback for our function and pass returnarray. I hope there is a better, and more clean version than that?

Comment: You might consider moving the whole thing into the asynchronous callback or into a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I hope there is a better, and more clean version than that?

[**Promises.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) Create an array of promises, one for each element, and wait for them to resolve. Since you already have an array, is fairly easy to map it to an array of promises and pass it to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const myFunction = (inputarray) => {
  return Promise.all(inputarray.map(element => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let returnelement = {
      a: element.A,
      b: element.B
    }
    if (returnelement.b == 5){
      MyType.find({ key: returnelement.b }, (err, value) => {
        returnelement.c = value;
        resolve(returnelement);
        // handle error?
        // reject(err);
      });
    } else {
       resolve(returnelement);
    }
  })));
}

myFunction([...])
  .then(resultArray => console.log(resultArray))
  .catch(error => console.log(error)))
```

Of course `myFunction` returns a promise now, so what ever calls `myFunction` has to be able to deal with that.

---

As @Tomalak pointed out, mongoose actually returns promises itself, so we can simplify this a little to:

```
const myFunction = (inputarray) => {
  return Promise.all(inputarray.map(element => {
    let returnelement = {
      a: element.A,
      b: element.B
    }
    if (returnelement.b == 5){
      return MyType.find({ key: returnelement.b }).then(value => {
        returnelement.c = value;
        return returnelement;
      });
    }
    return Promise.resolve(returnelement);
  }));
}
```

Comment: Mongoose has native promise support, this code can be simplified a little more: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm, and no libraries required to get it to work. Thanks a lot! I think I need to use Promises a lot more, as the code ended up quite nice both inside the function and the calling code as well :)

Comment: @ØyvindBråthen: Yep, promises provide a nice API contract.

Comment: `return Promise.resolve(returnelement);` is not necessary. You can do `return returnelement;` directly. `Promise.all()` does not differentiate between promises and plain values.

Answer (score 0):

async and await are your friends on this one. You can do some stuff with Promise aware generators, but we'll stick with the simpler one.

```
function findData(key){

  return Promise.resolve(MyType.find({ key }));
}

async function myFunction(inputarray){
  let returnarray = [];
  for (let element of inputarray){
    let returnelement = {
      a: element.A,
      b: element.B
    }
    if (returnelement.b == 5){
      returnelement.c = await findData(returnelement.b);
    }
    returnarray.push(returnelement);
  }
  return returnarray;
}
```

The cherry on top would be using a library such a [asynquence](https://github.com/getify/asynquence).

Comment: You might want to explain what needs to be done to get `async/await` working.

Answer (score 0):

You can write and execute synchronous code with [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS):

```
function myFunction(inputarray) {
    var returnarray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<inputarray.length; i++){
        var element = inputarray[i];
        var returnelement = {
            a: element.A,
            b: element.B
        };
        if (returnelement.b == 5){
            MyType.find({ key: returnelement.b }, function(err, value){
                returnelement.c = value;
                SynJS.resume(_synjsContext); //<-- indicates that callback is finished
            });
            SynJS.wait(); //<-- waits for callback to finish
        }
        returnarray.push(returnelement);
    }
    return returnarray;
}
```

Then you can call function like this:

```
SynJS.run(myFunction, null, function (ret) {
    console.log('result:', ret);
});
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Is it acceptable to promote my own library as part of a real answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298734/218196)